# How to specify typed parameters in REST request?

Tags: php, javascript, ruby-on-rails, node.js, rest

It is a bit of generic question. Many frameworks outside has **somehow** got their own solution on this, but those are somehow limited to their own implementation.

Request to RESTful web services is in plain text, how would you effectively type-cast them? Despite PHP has type-hinting, and This proves especially difficult when it comes to constants, `null` types, `undefined` in javascript, or `nil` and `nothing` in Basic.

For medium to big sized projects, casting them in a per method basis seems impractical.

This is more of theoretical than a coding question, but you are welcome to explain your point with code.

**NOTE:** We are talking in the context of PHP, NodeJS and RoR for the best/common practise and assumptions. ASP.NET web service and Java web method has their own strict syntax for this so I'm excluding them here.

Answer (score 0):

The REST protocol isn't involved with the content being sent and recieved, it only specifies actions (GET,PUT,DELETE,etc.) on resources (specified with URIs). What happens as a result of these actions is completely up to you.

I'm in JavaScript for 90% of the time which is a dynamic language. So I guess your question is more about how to use dynamic languages in a static way ? Each language has different ways to type check and libraries to assist. In terms of REST maybe you might find http://json-schema.org/ as a useful way of specifying typed JSON. Implemented in various ways: http://json-schema.org/implementations.html